# hadoop not writing output to file

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm having trouble with my MapReduce code. My code is going to write the max high stock and corresponding name from input to an output file. The problem is that zero bytes are being written and I get an empty file in the output.

**HighestStock.java**

```
JobConf conf = new JobConf(HighestStock.class);
conf.setJobName("Highest Stock");

FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf, new Path(args[0]);
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]);

conf.setMapperClass(HighStockMapper.class);
conf.setReducerClass(HighStockReducer.class);

conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

JobClient.runJob(conf);
```

**HighStockMapper.java**

```
 public class HighStockMapper implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
 public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String line = value.toString();
            String[] tokens = line.split(",");
            String name = tokens[0];
               int high = (int) Double.parseDouble(tokens[3]);
               context.write(new Text(name), new IntWritable(high);
             }
```

**HighStockReducer.java**

```
public class HighStockReducer extends MapReduceBase
implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
      public void reduce (Tex key, Iterator<IntWritable> values,
            OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
      throws IOExceptiion {
            int maxValue = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            while (values.hasNext()) {
                  maxValue = Math.max(maxValue, values.next().get());
            }
            output.collect(key, new IntWritable(maxValue));
       }
  }
```

Any help with debugging this would be much appreciated!

Screenshot of command-line results
[image: Screenshot of command-line results]

Answer (score 0):

You do have some typos in there. I wouldn't think this would even compile..

```
context.write(new Text(name), new IntWritable(high); // Missing closing )
```

and

```
throws IOExceptiion { // extra i
```

I take it this is not the actual code that you are running? Can you post the command-line results from running the job (including command and counter output)?

Edit: @anna-mai, your screenshot shows that the mapper is not emitting any records (Map output records = 0), so the problem is in your mapper.

I notice that you are missing extends MapReduceBase from your mapper. Try adding this:

```
public class HighStockMapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper
```

Comment: Yeah, I was retyping this from my virtual machine since it wouldn't let me copy back and forth. I'll post a new comment (found above this post) with a screenshot of what I get when I run it after compiling

Comment: You are mixing new hadoop api and old api ,in mapper you used context.write and in reducer you used output.collect is there any particular reason ?

Comment: No particular reason, I was basing my code off of an old code I found on GitHub so that's probably why there are some inconsistencies. What do I change so that the mapper and reducer api's match?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier you are mixing the older and newer implementation. You need to make the following changes to the mapper class

```
class HighStockMapper extends MapReduceBase  implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
        OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter arg3)
        throws IOException {
    String line = value.toString();
     String[] tokens = line.split(",");
     String name = tokens[0];
        int high = (int) Double.parseDouble(tokens[3]);
        output.collect(new Text(name), new IntWritable(high));

}
```

and the code runs fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried putting in exactly what you wrote but Eclipse told me that I had to rename map to map1. After creating the jar file and running it in command line I still get an empty file :/